# Resolving undeclared Identifier from Class

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have a Class, ArrayStates, that populates an array of the names of the US States.

```
#import "ArrayStates.h"
@implementation ArrayStates
@synthesize listOfStates;

NSMutableArray *listOfStates;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    //---initialize the array---
    listOfStates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //---add items---
    [listOfStates addObject:@"ALABAMA"];


    [listOfStates addObject:@"WYOMING"];
    // [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

If in the body program (.h) I

```
#import "ArrayStates.h"
```

Why am I getting "Undeclared Identifier" when I try and reference "listOfStates" as in

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [listOfStates count];
}
```

Comment: have you declared the array as property ?

Answer (score 2):

Declare your array as a global variable in the .h file
and also have a look at [here](http://maniacdev.com/2009/07/global-variables-in-iphone-objective-c/), and please understand about [global variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable) and [local variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable).

Comment: But I thought if I declare it locally in the class and then #import that code in it is compiled/linked to that body module and the variables behave locally within that module.

Answer (score 0):

Wrtie this in your .m file it will work. Remove instance of listOfStates from .h file alonf with property.

```
#import "ArrayStates.h"

 @interface ArrayStates() {
NSMutableArray *listOfStates;
}

@implementation ArrayStates

- (void)viewDidLoad {
//---initialize the array---
listOfStates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//---add items---
[listOfStates addObject:@"ALABAMA"];
[listOfStates addObject:@"WYOMING"];
[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm sure this is the right approach but something not quit right. ArrayStates.h has all *listOfSTates references removes and is stark/base.

Comment: .h now generates 4 errors with your code - @interface ArrayStates() { NSMutableArray *listOfStates; } - Cannot declare extension for "ArraySates" after class implementation. NSMutableArray *listOfSTates; Cannot declare variable inside ATinterface or ATprotocol and -(void)viewDIDLad { Expected '.' after method prototype.

Comment: What you meant was in .h put 

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

ATinterface ArrayStates : NSObject


{
    NSMutableArray *listOfStates;
}


ATend


and in .m put

#import "ArrayStates.h"

ATimplementation ArrayStates

- (void)viewDidLoad {

That gets rid of the errors but listOfStates is still undeclared in the body module.

Comment: sorry something i was written wrongly...but now its correct.The listOfStates now your private instance variable...you can not access it from out side of the class.

Comment: THis is still generating errors - I'll set this up as a new question so I can show the code clearly and everting is contiguated in these comments... Many thanks.

Comment: @EdwardHasted, you miss scope of variable some where that why this error occur.